# When is Shieldmeet?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, lore

The Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide states on page 15 that Shieldmeet is a Quadrennial holiday between Flamerule and Eleasis. This is also the case in accordance to the wiki. The Dungeon Master's Guide however states Shieldmeet to be between Hammer and Alturiak on page 33. I am not sure what source(s) is more accurate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### The Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide is Correct

**When in doubt, refer to *more recent* materials first.**

At least, that's the rule I'd use in this case. Errata is constantly being discovered in the earlier materials of D&D 5e. So it may be a better idea to refer to the most recently released content (In this case, the Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide) as opposed to the DMG.

However, **since errata is so common** in this edition, there are two possibilities as to what happened:

- The SCAG was erroneously printed with a later representation of Shieldmeet.
- The DMG was erroneously printed with an earlier representation of Shieldmeet.

**There must be some way to get more Forgotten Realms information to cross-compare...**

But wait! We do! Forgotten Realms is a long-standing world in the D&D universe, as such this question actually should not be restricted to just 5e. If we refer to the **D&D 3e Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting** we see the following:

> (*Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting 3rd Edition p. 77 : Shieldmeet*) **Shieldmeet** is added to the Faerunian calendar as a "*leap day*" **immediately following Midsummer night.**

So there you have it. The Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide fixed the errata within the DMG. So use it as the basis for when Shieldmeet is.

*Fun fact: Along with the erroneous printing of when Shieldmeet is. **Eleasis** is also misspelled in the DMG as **Eleasias***

Comment: Thank you for that, in our group we decided to restrict ourselves only to the current - edition content, and this did create a problem as seen here. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No problem. Never forget to check the older editions when it comes to Forgotten Realms lore. There are so many resources out there beyond the 5e rulebooks. Hope that helps out your campaign!

Comment: @PremierBromanov Pretty bold of them. What if they made more errata? ;) Interesting though, where is it mentioned so I can refer to it in the future? In the first few pages?

Comment: @D.Webber Well now I can't find it, so I'm retracting my statement until I can find out if I had actually read it

Comment: @PremierBromanov No problem, if you find it toss me a PM or something. I'm always curious about little tidbits I miss.

Comment: [DMG errata](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMG_Errata.pdf) mention sheildmeet, but I don't know the FR calendar well enough to know if the the erratum clarifies this question. Worth incorporating into your answer?